# Show/Hide toggle on link requires two clicks unless style defined inline

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, toggle

HTML

```
    <a data-info-id="info1" onclick="toggleLink();" href="#">Click here for more     information</a>
   <div id="info1" border="0">
    More information here
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #info1 {
    display:none;
 }
```

JS

```
        function toggleLink()
    {
         var elem=document.getElementById("info1");
         var hide = elem.style.display =="none";
         if (hide) {
             elem.style.display="block";
        } 
        else {
           elem.style.display="none";
        }
    }
```

PROBLEM

When the CSS is external and not inline it requires you to initially click the link twice before it properly shows and hides the info1 DIV.

SOLUTION IS TO MAKE THE STYLE INLINE, BUT WHY?

```
    <a data-info-id="info1" onclick="toggleLink();" href="#">Click here for more </a>       
<div id="info1" border="0" style="display:none";>
More information here
</div>
```

I want to use it with the following CSS then create an array with a listener for id=info1, id=info2 .... id=info20.

```
    [id^="info"]  { /* gets all elements where id starting with info */
    display: none;
```

}

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wfxpu/84/)

Comment: why can't you try simple jquery toggle functionality `$("#info1").toggle();` ?

Comment: OP did not specify that jquery was being used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var hide = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).display =="none";
```

instead of:

```
var hide = elem.style.display =="none";
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wfxpu/85/

Edit (explanation): This works because it checks for the computed style, which includes any styles set by classes or in stylesheets as well as inline styles. What you had originally only checked for the style in the inline style tag, which is not present when you are using a class/style from a stylesheet (in your case your code worked after the second click because after clicking you added an inline style). Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent fix thank you now I'll have to find out why that works.